# How to add the file names of the file used to import text data

Tags: vba, excel

I found a Macro that works great for importing data from text files in a specified directory.

I don’t have any real experience writing in VBA but was wondering if there is a way to take the code below and add the ability to put the name of the file the macro retrieved the data from into a column (*like column A*).

I am using this for searching 100+ logs for a specific data and having the ability to import all the data from those logs into excel makes it really easy. Now I just need a way to see which file the data came from. Thanks in advance, I look forward to learning something new.

**Macro**:

```
Sub ReadFilesIntoActiveSheet()
    Dim fso As FileSystemObject
    Dim folder As folder
    Dim file As file
    Dim FileText As TextStream
    Dim TextLine As String
    Dim Items() As String
    Dim i As Long
    Dim cl As Range

    ' Get a FileSystem object
    Set fso = New FileSystemObject

    ' get the directory you want
    Set folder = fso.GetFolder("My File Path")

    ' set the starting point to write the data to
    Set cl = ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1)

    ' Loop thru all files in the folder
    For Each file In folder.Files
        ' Open the file
        Set FileText = file.OpenAsTextStream(ForReading)

        ' Read the file one line at a time
        Do While Not FileText.AtEndOfStream
            TextLine = FileText.ReadLine

            ' Parse the line into | delimited pieces
            Items = Split(TextLine, "|")

            ' Put data on one row in active sheet
            For i = 0 To UBound(Items)
                cl.Offset(0, i).Value = Items(i)
            Next

            ' Move to next row
            Set cl = cl.Offset(1, 0)
        Loop

        ' Clean up
        FileText.Close
    Next file

    Set FileText = Nothing
    Set file = Nothing
    Set folder = Nothing
    Set fso = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    cl.value = file.Name
    ' Put data on one row in active sheet
    For i = 0 To UBound(Items)
        cl.Offset(0, i+1).Value = Items(i)
    Next
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I didnt realize it was so easy.  Thank you, problem solved!